# How to run sudo access without password in unix

Tags: linux, unix, redhat, sudoers

I have set up sudoers.d file unix as below:--

```
User_Alias  OOZIEUSERS1 = user1, user2
Runas_Alias  APP1 =  oozie
Cmnd_Alias SU_APP1 = /bin/su - oozie
OOZIEUSERS1   ALL = (root) SU_APP1 
OOZIEUSERS1   ALL = (APP1) ALL
```

However by setting in the above way everytime whenever I login as say user1 and then do following:-

```
sudo su - oozie
```

Its asking for password of the user.

How can I implement such that "oozie"(appln ID) doesn't ask for password at all for all users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this su question](http://superuser.com/questions/405715/ubuntu-linux-su-disable-password)

Comment: It seems you want `OOZIEUSERS1` to be able to run anything as user `oozie` without prompting for password, hence you want `sudo su - oozie` to work. I personally think it is better to put `OOZIEUSERS1  ALL=(oozie) NOPASSWD: ALL`. `user1` can then run `sudo -u oozie -s`.

Comment: Or if you need to simulate initial login run `sudo -u oozie -i`.

Answer (score 1):

Sudoers syntax is

```
username hostname=(as user name) command
```

so

```
%users ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/path/to/oozie
```

Note that you need full path to binary

Answer (score 0):

you can specify in the sudoers file NOPASSWD 
see [sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)
... I have tested finally, and it works - just create a file in /etc/sudoers.d with the content :

```
User_Alias  OOZIEUSERS1 = user1, user2
Runas_Alias  APP1 = oozie
Cmnd_Alias SU_APP1 = /bin/su - oozie
OOZIEUSERS1   ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:SU_APP1
OOZIEUSERS1   ALL = (APP1) ALL
```

And I obtained (w/o entering passwd):

```
pierre@crapaud:~$ sudo su - user2
user2@crapaud:~$ sudo su - oozie
oozie@crapaud:~$
```

Comment: Looks like,in sudoers.d its not working.

Comment: This user wishes to disable the password only for `su`.

Comment: strange, that is working on my install. Did you add NOPASSWD:

Comment: ok sjsam,  I will check with su later today ;)

Comment: I have clarified the question even further.Please read the last line.